# Is it possible to integrate rest-assured in my cucumber-jvm (selenium) project?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber, rest-assured

help me with how to integrate rest-assured in cucumber-jvm project.. As i said mostly using it for UI testing..

Any help?? Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see [Allure Cucumber-JVM Adaptor](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-cucumber-jvm-adaptor)